# How to inject a service to the main controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I was able to inject AuthDetails service to other components of my app, but I am having trouble injecting AuthDetails service to my main controller in the app, I have tried following but it does not work. It says: Uncaught ReferenceError: AuthDetails is not defined

```
MPlayApp.controller('MainCtrl','AuthDetails', [AuthDetails,
function MainCtrl(AuthDetails) {
    var subscription = AuthDetails.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
        console.log(d);
        if(d.success){
            this.loggedIn = true;
        }
    });
}]);
```

I have added the service to app as follows

```
var MPlayApp = angular.module('MPlayApp', [
// ...which depends on the MPlayApp module
'player',
'core',
'userMenu',
'home',
'songUpload',
'loginSignUp',
'details',
'angularSoundManager',
'angularFileUpload',
'ngAnimate',
'rx',
'ui.router',
'core.auth'
]);
```

AuthDetails service is under core.auth module

Comment: `MPlayApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['AuthDetails',
function (AuthDetails) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. It should be

```
MPlayApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['AuthDetails', function MainCtrl(AuthDetails) {
```

Or better, use ng-annotate, and let it generate this ugly, error-prone syntax for you during the build, from the basic, intuitive syntax:

```
MPlayApp.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl(AuthDetails) {
```